# PyQt Signal positional argument disappearing

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm writing a small application in Python 3.6 and PyQt 5.13.1 to compare file checksums for directories across multiple remote servers. I'm trying to split out the main logic of my application into its own thread, and from that thread use a threadpool to create several more threads to SSH into the remote servers and get information back.

Everything is mostly working, except when the signal I have made for the SSH threads is called, one of the positional arguments ends up missing and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ssh_result() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Here is a stripped down version of what I currently have, but is exhibiting the same issue:

```
import paramiko
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QThreadPool, QRunnable, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QObject


class SSHWorkerSignals(QObject):
    result = pyqtSignal('PyQt_PyObject', 'PyQt_PyObject')


class SSHWorker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SSHWorker, self).__init__()
        self.ssh_signals = SSHWorkerSignals()
        self.ssh_server = 'test.server.corp'

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
            ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
            ssh_client.connect(self.ssh_server, port=22, username='test', password='test')
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('uname -a')
            std_out = str(stdout.read())
            self.ssh_signals.result.emit(self.ssh_server, std_out)
        except Exception as e:
            self.ssh_signals.result.emit(self.ssh_server, str(e))
        finally:
            ssh_client.close()


class CompareWorker(QObject):
    done = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(CompareWorker, self).__init__()
        self.ssh_threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.ssh_threadpool.setMaxThreadCount(10)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def execute(self):
        ssh_worker = SSHWorker()
        ssh_worker.ssh_signals.result.connect(MainWindow.ssh_result)
        self.ssh_threadpool.start(ssh_worker)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.button_compare = QPushButton('Compare')
        self.button_compare.clicked.connect(self.compare)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button_compare)

    def compare(self):
        compare_thread = QThread(self)
        self.compare_worker = CompareWorker()

        compare_thread.started.connect(self.compare_worker.execute)
        self.compare_worker.done.connect(compare_thread.quit)
        self.compare_worker.done.connect(self.compare_worker.deleteLater)

        self.compare_worker.moveToThread(compare_thread)
        compare_thread.start()

    def ssh_result(self, server, message):
        print('server: ', server, ', result: ', message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec_()
```

If I change the ssh_result() function so that message is an optional argument (`def ssh_result(self, server, message=''):`), I can see that the first positional argument is disappearing, leaving what should be the second argument to be the first instead, like so:

```
server:  [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed , result:
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `MainWindow.ssh_result` is not a method that belongs to some instance, so the first "self" parameter does not exist. I also don't see the need for the creation of CompareWorker.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
# ...
class SSHWorkerSignals(QObject):
    result = pyqtSignal(
        "PyQt_PyObject", "PyQt_PyObject"
    )  # or pyqtSignal(object, object)


class SSHWorker(QRunnable):
    # ...


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.button_compare = QPushButton("Compare")
        self.button_compare.clicked.connect(self.compare)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button_compare)

        self.ssh_threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.ssh_threadpool.setMaxThreadCount(10)

    def compare(self):
        ssh_worker = SSHWorker()
        ssh_worker.ssh_signals.result.connect(self.ssh_result)
        self.ssh_threadpool.start(ssh_worker)

    def ssh_result(self, server, message):
        print("server: ", server, ", result: ", message)


# ...
```

Comment: I had originally broken out the CompareWorker because the main window has a status bar that is supposed to update in the background, but the status bar wouldn't update while the compare function was running. Other questions I had found while googling suggested breaking out the main logic into its own thread so that the UI doesn't become unresponsive. Is there a way to do that without moving CompareWorker to its own thread?

Comment: It is not necessary to use CompareWorker. I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it seems that you are trying to solve it without understanding what the magic solution you want to implement implies. Why do you want to create a CompareWorker? If you want to update the GUI (status bar) from another then you must use signals.

Comment: Initially I had a solution very similar to what you proposed. The compare function would ask for login information, then call another function to create threads using threadpool and SSHWorker. After creating the threads, the other function would then try to use the setText() method of the label in the status bar to change the text, but these changes never occurred. To get around that, I moved most of the compare function's functionality to CompareWorker and its own thread, and then used signals to change the text (which works). That is when I ran into the problem that I initially posted.

Comment: @SeanEvans I emphasize, it is not necessary to create CompareWorker. With the code you provide I do not see the need for what I will not propose in my solution, if you provide the necessary information that indicates me in which case my solution fails then I will see if the CompareWorker is necessary but as already indicated in the code that you currently provide It is not necessary. We are discussing the same which is boring me. goodbye.

Comment: I have poured over the code I have written and rethought some assumptions I had made, and I realized you were correct. I thought that something was preventing my application from updating the statusbar, but the issue was simply that the GUI was not being redrawn before I was starting a long running loop. Calling `app.processEvents()` before the loop caused the status bar to update. I apologize for wasting your time, but thank you for your help nonetheless.